# Im facing this error when adding new data to sqlite in flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, sqflite

Exception has occurred.
SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(2 values for 3 columns (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contact
(
title,
deskripsi,
date
)
VALUES (?,?)) sql 'INSERT INTO contact
(
title,
deskripsi,
date
)
VALUES (?,?)' args [judul, deskripsi, date]})

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 question marks, because you have 3 column, but only 2 provided right now 
please change from

```
INSERT INTO contact ( title, deskripsi, date ) VALUES (?,?)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO contact ( title, deskripsi, date ) VALUES (?,?,?)
```